# Why the maximum number of points of tangency between a line and a generic plane curve is two?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory

[image]
The picture comes from this book [Catastrophe theory, page 57](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-58124-3).

I can understand it intuitively, but how can we prove it?

Comment: Please know that [pictures of text are discouraged here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged).

Comment: What are your thoughts? What leads you to intuit that this ought to be true? Are you familiar with transversality?

Comment: @Kajelad : If there exists a line tangent to the curve at 3 points, then we can pull up the curve a little near the first point of tangency such that the line tangent to the curve at only 2 points. I think that a rigorous proof may have something to do with the dimensions of lines in plane, which is 2.

Comment: For algebraic curves, one can do even better: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem

Comment: @JohnnyLemmon : Could you give more details or some reference books about the proof?

Comment: Sure! Just to clarify, I wrote "better" as in "more precise", but the result is quite different. Consider an algebraic curve defined by a polynomial $p(x,y)$ of degree $n$. When you intersect it with a line $a x+b y=c$, the common points are the solutions of the polynomial equation $q(x):=p\left(x,(c-a x)/b\right)=0$. As $q$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, you get at most $n$ solutions. If you do this on the complex projective plane it turns out that the solutions are *exactly $n$*, counting with multiplicities. You can find the more general statement in Shafarevich's book, I think.